# Change detection not working when updating FormArray inside FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Using reactive forms and change detection on push.

I have been searching all over SO for how to do this example I feel like this s fairly common, however, I can't seem to find a good example of how to properly do this.

When attempting to update a FormArray that contains a list of FormGroup inside of a subscribe inside ngOnInit the FormArray object is updated but unless change detection is forced on the component the view will not update the FormArray groups. All other controls that are updated in this manner are working. So it feels like however I'm trying to update the FormArray is wrong and that I should not and don't want to force change detection.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from "@angular/core";
import { JournalTransactionService } from "app/accounting/shared-services/journal-transaction.service";
import { JournalEntry } from "accountingModels";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from "@angular/forms";
import { EntryLine } from "app/accounting/models/journal";

@Component({
  selector: "general-journal",
  templateUrl: "./general-journal.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./general-journal.component.scss"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class GeneralJournalComponent implements OnInit {
  journalEntry: JournalEntry;
  journalEntryForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _journalTransactionService: JournalTransactionService, private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  get entryLines(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.journalEntryForm.get("entryLines");
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.journalEntryForm = this._formBuilder.group(
      {
        transactionId: "",
        transactionDate: "",
        autoReversalDate: "",
        journalEntryType: "",
        entryLines: this._formBuilder.array([])
      }
    );
    this._journalTransactionService.getTransaction("", 80).subscribe(journalEntry => {
      journalEntry.entryLines.forEach(entryLine => {
        this.entryLines.push(this.entryLineMapper(entryLine));
      });

      this.journalEntryForm.patchValue(
        {
          transactionId: journalEntry.transactionId,
          transactionDate: journalEntry.transactionDate,
          autoReversalDate: journalEntry.autoReversalDate,
          journalEntryType: journalEntry.journalEntryType
        }
      );
    });
  }


  private entryLineMapper = (entryLine: EntryLine): FormGroup => {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      accountId: entryLine.accountId,
      controlId: entryLine.controlId,
      debit: entryLine.debit,
      credit: entryLine.credit,
      description: entryLine.description,
    })
  }
}
```

The relevant section of the html. If you type into any other field that is bound such as the transaction id then change detection is run and the table is filled out. If you manually trigger change detection after patch value in the subscribe block the table is filled out.

```
  <tbody formArrayName="entryLines">
      <tr *ngFor="let entryLine of entryLines.controls; index as i" [formGroupName]="i">
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="accountId">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="controlId">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="debit">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="credit">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="description">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**Update**

To get around this issue for now I'm creating two components one that is the base component for a feature and one that is wrapping the form. This is allowing me to pass the data for building the form as an input to the form component thus allowing OnPush detection to work. I'm sort of okay with this but it still feels like a FormArray should be able to have FormGroups or controls added via a subscription and have the new values updated in the UI. I think if the FormArray controls was an observable of AbstracControl this would work. If anyone has a better solution let us all know.

Comment: If I turn of OnPush change detection the formArray is showing up as expected. I think this is because the *ngFor is not seeing changes to the controls when OnPush is used. I could also manually trigger change detection in the subscribe function body of the onInit. I feel like there should be an exposed property on the FormArray that would be and observable<AbstractControls[]> and that way you could use OnPush with a reactive form. Can anyone confirm that this is the issue and those are the only two ways to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

don't use `map` instead just use `push`.

```
private entryLineBuilder = (entryLines: EntryLine[]): FormArray => {
    return this._formBuilder.array(entryLines.push(this.entryLineMapper));
  }
```

Because you're changing the array by pushing, that should in turn trigger angulars change detection.

Comment: Sorry that code is not being called. That was just a failed attempt that is hanging around. I'm just calling the entryLineMapper and pushing to the formArray inside the subscribe. I'll update the post so it's not there to confuse anyone.

Comment: Ah awkward :/ Yeah I see that now - ok so that bit looks fine. Are you getting data back data within that subscribe for `journalEntry`? So it does add a new line in the FormArray but the view doesn't update?

Comment: Yeah that is reading just a json file with two lines. And when the component loads all the fields that are not in the form array that are patched in that subscribe show up in the UI. But the lines in the FormArray are not there. If you change an input value of say the transactionId then change detection is fired and the lines will appear. Also if you mark for change detection in the subscribe it also will work but that seems wrong.

Comment: So you can't see them in the view yes? Have you checked to see if the value `entryLines` has the new control in it via console.log/debug?

Comment: Yes I have logged to the console as the last line of the subscribe function body and the formArray is correct with two values that are FormGroup and have the correct values.

Comment: From previous experience I think you will need to use change detection to trigger the view to update. I've done something similar with a form repeater and used `ComponentFactoryResolver` and `resolveComponentFactory` to inject the element into the view.

Comment: But why would the rest of the form be displaying in the view and not the FormArray elements? To me it seems like if you can set any values of the formGroup you should be able to set all values of a form group including the FormArray. Like I said in the question I can force change detection to happen but it feels wrong for the reason mentioned in this comment.

Comment: I was under the assumption the `formArray` was getting updated on the fly i.e. dynamically - if that's not the case then I agree with you. Have you tried using `journalEntry.entryLines` value for *ngFor rather than the controls? https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms  is very useful for building reactive form elements on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you find the answer yet. Use `removeAt` will trigger the change detection in Angular 8.